# AngularJS: scope of ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-init

What is the scope of ng-init in Angular?  Here's a simple example that demonstrates my question:

```
<div ng-init="model = { year: '2013'}">
    <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2012'">2012</a> |
    <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2013'">2013</a>
    <div>Showing {{ model.year }}</div>
    <hr />
</div>
<div ng-init="model = { year: '2013'}">
    <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2012'">2012</a> |
    <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2013'">2013</a>
    <div>Showing {{ model.year }}</div>
</div>
```

Live example available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HkioewOzzglvFMKDPdIf?p=preview

Is seems that ng-init scope is shared among the 2 `div[ng-init]`.  For example, if you click on the year '2012' in either section, it changes the `year` property in both sections.

Is there a way to tell angular to create a new scope for each ng-init and thereby clicking the '2012' year will only impact the section that it belongs to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ng-init` does not create a new scope, it evaluates an expression in the current scope. In your example, both your `ng-init` are in **the same scope**, changing the same model property will affect the other. If you need separate scope, you could try `ng-controller`.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="model = { year: '2013'}">
      <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2012'">2012</a> |  <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2013'">2013</a>
      <div>Showing {{ model.year }}</div>
      <hr />
    </div>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="model = { year: '2013'}">
      <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2012'">2012</a> |  <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2013'">2013</a>
      <div>Showing {{ model.year }}</div>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PTg9fpzj6DQRUeY0JFru?p=preview)

**Side notes:** In this case, you don't need ngInit, just initialize the value directly in your controller.

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than
>   ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: But then, if you're using `ng-controller`, `ng-init` becomes useless. Or at least confusing. Better to put the initialization code inside the controller.

Comment: @7hi4g0: I agree. But I think it's not much related to this question. This question is about scope of ng-init.

Comment: Still I think is better to put some kind of warning on the answer since angularjs' docs itself states that `ng-if` only makes sense together with `ng-repeat`

Comment: @7hi4g0: When you are using ng-repeat in your page and the list you are iterating on is resault of an ajax request, you **have** to use ng-init.

Comment: @7hi4g0 Of course you don't.   Make your ajax call, update your model, and your ng-repeat will act appropriately.

Comment: The angular docs have been updated to include one other valid usage of ng-init, namely server-side includes: "There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting."

Answer (score 3):

Since `ng-if` creates a new scope, you can accomplish it just by:

```
<div ng-if="true" ng-init="model = { year: '2013'}">
```

Comment: or simply <div ng-if="model = { year: '2013'}">

Answer (score 0):

Hello to clarify and find the solution, could you please try out the solution given below

```html
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myAngularApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl1', function ($scope) { });
    app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope) { });
</script>

<body ng-app="myAngularApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl1" ng-init="model = { year: '2012'}">
        <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2012'">2012</a> | <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2013'">2013</a>
        <div>Showing {{ model.year }}</div>        
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl2" ng-init="model = { year: '2013'}">
        <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2012'">2012</a> | <a href="" ng-click="model.year = '2013'">2013</a>
        <div>Showing {{ model.year }}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Here you can succeed the idea you need to implement